# Can I use submit with button in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I want to submit a form , but before submitting it , I want to invoke a button 
that calls a JS function :

```
<input name="" type="submit" value="SEND">  // <----- submit this later


<button type="button" id="button" onClick="validateForm()">SEND THIS BEFORE</button>  // <<-- call this before submitting the form
```

Is there a way to combine there together ?

Thanks

Comment: just use the function to .submit() the form

Comment: the docs are your friend http://api.jquery.com/submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Wrap it around a `form` tag and add an `onsubmit` attribute.

```
<form onsubmit="validateForm()">
      <input type="submit" value="SEND"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onclick function you just need to use the `.submit()` inside the function to send your form whenever you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do various things, such as:

```
$("#form").on("submit", function(){
  // do stuff here
});
```

Or

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
  // do stuff here
  $("#form").submit();
});
```